# Warning "Unknown or uninitialised column: `ntree`." when trying to pass hyperparameters to a learner with package mlr

Tags: hyperparameters, mlr

## problem

I want to do a grid search with different hyperparameters that are provided by a self-made grid. But when I am running the code I get a warning: "Unknown or uninitialised column: `ntree`."

## example data

```
age <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 50,sd = 10)))
sex <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2)))
l1 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l2 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l3 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l4 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,sex,l1,l2,l3,l4))
```

In reality I have 12 labels, but I left the others out to make it easier to look at. The idea is that l1 untill l4 are logical vectors. Somehow that doesn't work, so I hope you can fix that. But be aware that that is not my main question.

## create grid

```
gs <- list(ntree = c(50,100,150,200,300,500,550),mtry = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>% cross_df()
```

## select hyperparameters

```
  for (h in 1:nrow(gs)) {
    ntree_entry <- gs$ntree[h]
    mtry_entry <- gs$mtry[h]
    (...)
    lrn <- makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper(lrn, order = NULL) 
    lrn <- setPredictType(lrn,"prob")
    task <- makeMultilabelTask(data = data[train_lines,], target = label_bact) 
    mod <- mlr::train(lrn,task)
    }
```

On the place of (...) I have tried two different ways to get the hyperparameters into the learner:

## option 1: pass hyperparameters to the learner

```
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest",ntree = ntree_entry,mtry = mtry_entry)
```

## option 2: pass hyperparameters to the learner

```
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")
lrn <- setHyperPars(lrn,par.vals = list(ntree = ntree_entry,mtry = mtry_entry))
```

## check

The console tells me that the hyperparameters are in the learner:

```
>lrn
Learner classif.randomForest from package randomForest
Type: classif
Name: Random Forest; Short name: rf
Class: classif.randomForest
Properties: twoclass,multiclass,numerics,factors,ordered,prob,class.weights,oobpreds,featimp
Predict-Type: response
Hyperparameters: ntree=50,mtry=1
```

ntree and mtry are hyperparameters that are known to the makeLearner, because they are both in getParamSet:

```
> getParamSet("classif.randomForest")

                     Type  len   Def   Constr Req Tunable Trafo
ntree             integer    -   500 1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
mtry              integer    -     - 1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
replace           logical    -  TRUE        -   -    TRUE     -
classwt     numericvector <NA>     - 0 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
cutoff      numericvector <NA>     -   0 to 1   -    TRUE     -
strata            untyped    -     -        -   -   FALSE     -
sampsize    integervector <NA>     - 1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
nodesize          integer    -     1 1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
maxnodes          integer    -     - 1 to Inf   -    TRUE     -
importance        logical    - FALSE        -   -    TRUE     -
localImp          logical    - FALSE        -   -    TRUE     -
proximity         logical    - FALSE        -   -   FALSE     -
oob.prox          logical    -     -        -   Y   FALSE     -
norm.votes        logical    -  TRUE        -   -   FALSE     -
do.trace          logical    - FALSE        -   -   FALSE     -
keep.forest       logical    -  TRUE        -   -   FALSE     -
keep.inbag        logical    - FALSE        -   -   FALSE     -
```

## Question

Why do I get the message "Unknown or uninitialised column: `ntree`"?
Although it is only a warning, not an error, I am afraid that it will only use the first line of the grid that I created. The size of the models seem to confirm that. They all have the same size.
I hope that someone can help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the [manual](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html) how to do tuning with mlr? Your code looks unnecessary complicated. Also note that grid search is usually not a good choice for production and that mlr is deprecated since two years in favor of mlr3.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522745/warning-unknown-or-uninitialised-column-ntree-when-trying-to-pass-hyperpar).

Comment: Sorry for the cross-post.

Comment: So have you read the manual and considered using mlr3? It would help if you could post a reproducible example in one code block with less headings in your question.

Comment: see example data for reproducible example

Comment: Do you know if mlr3 will solve my question?

Comment: mlr3 is not made for multilabel classification yet . https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/multilabel.html

Comment: So it appears that you have to make the grid in mlr to use it. For example code see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640953/feature-names-stored-in-object-and-newdata-are-different-using-mlr-package?noredirect=1#comment119651508_67640953