# Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different! using mlr package

Tags: xgboost, multilabel-classification, mlr

I am trying to make a multilabel classification model for XGBoost. I have one that works for RF, but when I try this code below for XGBoost I get the error:

```
"Error in predict.xgb.Booster(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), ...) : 
Feature names stored in 'object' and 'newdata' are different!
```

And as I did not assign it train data and test data or 'newdata' (this is done by the makeResampleDesc() ) I don't know how to fix this error.

Any ideas?

Example data

```
library(mlr)
library(xgboost)
lab <- c("l1","l2","l3","l4","l5")
age <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 50,sd = 10)))
sex <- c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2)))
l1 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l2 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l3 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l4 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
l5 <- as.logical(c(round(rnorm(120,mean = 0.5,sd = 0.2))))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,sex,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5))
data[,lab]<- lapply(data[,lab],FUN = as.logical)
```

Create learner

```
learner <- "classif.xgboost"
lrn <- makeLearner(learner, objective = "multi:softprob") 
lrn <- makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper(lrn, order = NULL) 
lrn <- setPredictType(lrn,"prob")
```

Create grid

```
ps <- makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("max_depth", values = c(1,3,5)),
  makeDiscreteParam("eta",values = c(0.001,0.01,0.1))
)
```

Set up resampling method and tuning

```
ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method = "CV",iters = 5L)
```

Initiate evaluation vector

```
v_f1 <- c()
v_max_depth <- c()
v_eta <- c()
```

Actual model training

```
task <- makeMultilabelTask(data = data, target = lab) 
   
res <- tuneParams(lrn,task = task,resampling = rdesc, par.set = ps,
       control = ctrl, measures = multilabel.f1)

v_f1 <- c(v_f1,as.vector(res$y[1]))
v_max_depth <- c(v_max_depth,as.vector(res$x[1]))
v_eta <- c(v_eta,as.vector(res$x[4]))
```

Comment: Could you reduce this to a minimal example please?

Comment: I deleted the RF part and all but one measure. And to prevent cross-posting I added a link to stats exchange. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting errors when I try to run your code. Please include a complete and minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying! I can check my code tomorrow, hopefully in the morning. But in the meantime, we could check the libraries. I forgot to add them in the code. You need libraries "mlr" and "xgboost".

Comment: I changed the code. (vectors l1 till l5 are now logical vectors) On my computer I don't get extra errors anymore. Does it work at yours?

Comment: I'm getting `Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , lab) : undefined columns selected` when I run the "Example Data" block.

Comment: You are right, there was a mistake. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks -- this looks like a bug, I would open an issue for this.

Comment: OK. Thanks. How and where can I raise/report this issue?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type-bug&template=bug.md&title=

Comment: Thank you. This is the post https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2811